# How can I get data for a window of 24 hours from given timestamp

Tags: database, oracle

Let's say I have a table with date-timestamp column in a table and every time I pass a date and time to it, I want to get the data for last 24 hours from that timestamp.

say, on querying for `TIMESTAMP 23/03/2019 18:00:00`
it should filter out and give results for the following period:
`22/03/2019 18:00:01` to `23/03/2019 18:00:00`

Comment: And what's the question? Which queries have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an Interval expression to go back 1 day.

```
where timestamp_column > :v_timestamp - INTERVAL '1' DAY 
 AND  timestamp_column <= :v_timestamp --The date you want to pass.
```